# PLS00103: encountered the symbol "END"

Tags: sql, oracle, procedure

here is my procedure that is giving me the PLS00130: encountered the symbol "END"error. where is the problem?? am i missing any thing??

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GETHEATDATA(HEATNO NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
  FOR program IN (
    select program_id from rml_program where heat_id=HEATNO
    )
  LOOP
  select
  program.program_id,
    program.job_id,
    program.grade,
    count(t.semiproduct_cnt),
    max(t.charging_date),
    min(t.charging_date),
    max(t.reheating_date),
    min(t.reheating_date),
    count(t.rejecting_date),
    count(t.rolling_date),
    count(t.loss_date)
    from
    rml_semiproduct t
    where
    t.program_id = program.program_id;
  END LOOP;
  END;
  END GETHEATDATA;
```

Comment: Remove the end;?

Comment: Either remove the second last END or the last END GETHEATDATA

Comment: I tried but it give me errors-- Compilation errors for PROCEDURE STM.GETHEATDATA

Error: PLS-00302: component 'GRADE' must be declared
Line: 11
Text: program.grade,

Error: PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "PROGRAM"."GRADE": invalid identifier
Line: 11
Text: program.grade,

Error: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Line: 8
Text: select

Comment: @user3004692 As pointed by RLOG in the answer, you need to join the table which is having the grade column as the procedure does not know about grade column apart from either removing the second last END or the last END GETHEATDATA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things.  Firstly, remove the `END GETHEATDATA`, and secondly, you forgot to join on the program table.